# USB resets with Ubuntu 9.10

Tags: linux, usb, ubuntu-9.10, troubleshooting, external-hard-drive

Since the upgrade to Ubuntu 9.10 I have issues with getting USB device resets on my Maxtor OneTouch USB harddrive:

```
Nov  9 20:54:37 localhost kernel: [32459.100021] usb 2-2: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
Nov  9 21:54:37 localhost kernel: [36059.100017] usb 2-2: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
Nov  9 23:24:37 localhost kernel: [41459.112025] usb 2-2: reset high speed USB device using ehci_hcd and address 4
```

The device itself continues to work fine, the resets however wake the device out of its sleep state and thus cause it to spin up, which is very annoying.

Interestingly, as the log shows, the resets happen at pretty regular intervals (i.e. one hour or half an hour), not randomly.

An USB card reader seems to have the same issues, while another USB harddrive from a different manufactor works fine on the same PC.

What could be causing this and how could I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An upgrade to Ubuntu 10.04 seems to have fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Does this occur when the drive is mounted or umounted (or both)? If it's mounted are you certain nothing is accessing it?

Comment: It happens in both mounted and unmounted state. As far as I know nothing should be accessing the drive.